# Change method calls from Implicit type arguments to explicit

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a method with the following signature:

```
 public static TDestination Editable<TSource, TDestination>
          (TSource source, TDestination destination)
    {
      ...
    }
```

It is called hundreds of times like this:

```
Editable(source, destination);
```

I want to change it to

```
Editable<TSource, TDestination>(source, destination);
```

The reason for this is that I want to be able to get a list of all the type parameters that are actually used in calls to this method, without having to inspect each call site. If I could make the type parameters explicit at every call site, I could simply *search the source code* mechanically to get a list of all the type parameters that get passed to the method.

How can I do that with ReSharper, or another tool?

Comment: The type arguments specification are redundant. Why do you want to specify them?

Comment: The opposite way works but i don't think you can apply this rule because it doesn't exist. Resharper wants to simplify your code, it doesn't want to make it more verbose.

Comment: I want to specify them because I want to be able to do a search in the source code for the types that get passed to the method.

Comment: You can. Something  like this `Editable<int, int>(source, destination);`. What's your problem?

Comment: The problem is that this method is called 250+ times with different type arguments;

Comment: If you can't figure out how to get ReSharper to do this for you, and given your goal, you may want to consider creating a bunch of non-generic overloads and use ReSharper to help refactor the calls.

Comment: I want to record the calls. I want to know all of the type parameters that get passed to the method. The idea was that I don't need to go to each call sight. If I'm able to convert them all at one to explicitly pass the parameters, I can then write a script that reads the source code and lists all the type parameters that get passed to the method.

Comment: [When you ask a question, consider whether a reasonable person, knowing *nothing more than what you have put in the question text*, would have any counter-questions. If you think they would, *put the answers to those counter-questions in your question text*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108060/why-do-people-question-every-question/108070#108070) rather than waiting for comments asking what you actually want to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using `Resharper 2017.2.2`. Try the following steps and let me know how it works for you:

1. Position your cursor on the call that is missing the generic type arguments. In your case it will be at the end of the method name, before the opening parenthesis:

   ```
   Editable|(source, destination);
           ^ the pipe in the above line is your cursor
   ```
2. Hit alt + enter to open the quick fix tool window.
3. Locate the option named ***Insert inferred type arguments*** and expand the arrow to the right if you want to refactor at file, folder, project or solution level and click the desired option. Take a look at the below picture:

[image: Insert inferred type arguments]

3. This should insert all the inferred type arguments for the selected level.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This did help. I didn't know that context actions are different depending on where the cursor is on the method name. It's just not very intuitive. 

Thank you very much.